# Link class in python

Tags: python

im trying to do a class Player which contain a name a a deck of 17 card, which is another class. i was wondering how to assign each card to the players as my code just output the memory location like this for the deck of the player:

('Traineer1', [<**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196BFEE0>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196BFFA0>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196C0280>, <**main**.Traineer object at 0x00000227196BFC40>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196BFFA0>, <**main**.Traineer object at 0x00000227196BFCA0>, <**main**.Energy object at 0x00000227196BFD60>, <**main**.Traineer object at 0x00000227196BFC40>, <**main**.Traineer object at 0x00000227196BFC40>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196C02E0>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196BFFA0>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196C0040>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196BFE80>, <**main**.Energy object at 0x00000227196BFD60>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196C0340>, <**main**.Pokemon object at 0x00000227196C0100>, <**main**.Traineer object at 0x00000227196BFC40>])

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f'The pokemon name is {self.name}'

class Pokemon(Card):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,type,ability):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.hp = hp
        self.type = type
        self.ability = ability

    def __str__(self):
        return f'The pokemon {self.name} specs are: \nHp: {self.hp} \nType: {self.type} \nAbility: {self.ability}'

class Energy(Card):
    def __init__(self,name,symbol):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.symbol = symbol

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Symbol is: {self.symbol} for {self.name} Card.'

class Traineer(Card):
    def __init__(self,name,type,text,rule):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.type = type
        self.text = text
        self.rule = rule

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Traineer Card {self.name} specs are: \nType: {self.type} \nText: {self.text} \nRule: {self.rule}'

#Excellent
class player:
    def __init__(self,name,deck):
        self.name = name
        self.deck = deck

    def __str__(self):
        print(f'Player name and deck:\n {self.name,self.deck}')

def main():
    #Pokemon cards.
    Machoke = Pokemon('Machoke','50','Fighting','Crush')
    Alakazam = Pokemon('Alakazam','80','Electric','Sparkle')
    Charizard = Pokemon('Charizard','169','Fire','Burn')
    Gyarados = Pokemon('Gyarados','60','Water','Wave')
    Mewtwo = Pokemon('Mewtwo','140','Psychic','Hypnose')
    Charmeleon = Pokemon('Charmeleon','58','Plant','Seed')
    Jynx = Pokemon('Jynx','50','Psychic','Hypnose')
    Magikarp = Pokemon('Magikarp','50','Water','Wave')
    Wartortle = Pokemon('Wartortle','150','Plant','Seed')
    Abra = Pokemon('Abra','55','Fighting','Crush')
    Doduo = Pokemon('Doduo','33','Plant','Seed')
    Magnemite = Pokemon('Magnemite','80','Fighting','Crush')
    Pikachu = Pokemon('Pikachu','30','Electric','Sparkle')
    Squirtle = Pokemon('Squirtle','20','Water','Flood')
    Onix = Pokemon('Onix','70','Fighting','Crush')
    #Energy cards.
    Water_energy = Energy('Water energy','Blue drop')
    Fire_energy = Energy('Fire energy','Red flame')
    Psychic_energy = Energy('Psychic energy','Purple eye')
    #Traineer cards.
    Revive = Traineer('Revive','Support item','Can revive a passed pokemon','Can be used once per turn')
    Full_Heal = Traineer('Full Heal','Support item','Get your pokemon hp point to maximum',"Can be used once per turn. doesn't not work with passed pokemon")
    Super_Potion = Traineer('Super Potion','Support item','Give back 50 Hp point','Can be used once per turn')

#Typical

    #Lists with differents instances
    pokemon = [Machoke,Alakazam,Charizard,Gyarados,Mewtwo,Charmeleon,Jynx,Magikarp,Wartortle,Abra,Doduo,Magnemite,Pikachu,Squirtle,Onix]
    Traineercard = [Revive, Full_Heal, Super_Potion]
    Energycard = [Water_energy,Fire_energy,Psychic_energy]
    Deck = pokemon + Traineercard + Energycard

    print("The available cards are:")
    # Print list in loop.
    for i in Deck:
        print(i.name)

    print("\nThe available pokemon cards are:")
    for i in pokemon:
        print(i.name)

    print("\nThe available Energy cards are:")
    for i in Energycard:
        print(i.name)

    print("\nThe available Traineer cards are:")
    for i in Traineercard:
        print(i.name)

    player1 = player('Traineer1',random.choices(Deck,k=17))

    print(player1.__str__())




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is certainly a very finnicky way of doing it, but I think it should work for your needs:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        playerDeck = ""
        for i, item in enumerate(self.deck):
            if i:
                playerDeck = (playerDeck + ', ')
            playerDeck = (playerDeck + item.name)
        print(f'Player name and deck:\n {self.name,playerDeck}')
```

What it's doing is making a string, and appending the name of every item in your player's deck to it, so it's printable. I couldn't quite figure out how to get the names of the items direct from the list, maybe someone else could help with that (if it's possible - it should be.)